# How to open a .bat (batch file) in gcc (ex cygwin)?

Tags: cygwin, gnu

How do i open a batch file .bat file in GCC compiler ? what is the command to open it ? we use gcc for c programs to compile. But what is the command to open a .bat file ? Can we open it if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `system("example.bat");` Hope it will resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

.bat files have nothing to do with C programs...  So the C compiler has no need to compile it.